# Fetching data from API in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, react.js, axios

I'm using Axios to fetch data from an API, and don't know if this is the best way to deal with APIs in ReactJS or not. I want to know if anyone can suggest edits or something to make the code more efficient.

**api.js**

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const APIendpoint = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'https://1eb19101-0790-406f-90e0-ee35a2ff2d1f.mock.pstmn.io',
    timeout: 2000
});
```

**matchesAction.js**

```
import {FETCH_MATCHES} from './actionTypes';
import {APIendpoint} from '../api/api';

export const fetchMatches = () => dispatch => {
    const matchInstance = APIendpoint.get('/matches');
    matchInstance.then(response =>
        dispatch({
            type: FETCH_MATCHES,
            payload: response.data
        })
    );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be done in many ways based on your use case & code structure, but i feel this can be optimal way of structuring.

### api/services/index.js

```
import axios from 'axios';
export {default as MATCHES_API} from "./services/matches.js";

export const CONFIG_API = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://1eb19101-0790-406f-90e0-ee35a2ff2d1f.mock.pstmn.io',
  timeout: 2000
});
```

### api/services/matches.js

```
import CONFIG_API from "api/services";

const ERROR_MSG = "<generic message>";

export const matches = () => {
  return CONFIG_API.get("/matches").then(res => {
  // do some operations on data - if required 
    return {success: true, data: res.payload};
  }).catch(err => {
    return {success: false, message: ERROR_MSG || err.message};
  });
};
```

### actions/matchesAction.js

```
import {FETCH_MATCHES} from './actionTypes';
import {MATCHES_API} from "/api/services";

export const fetchMatches = () => dispatch => {
  matches.then((response) =>
    const {success} = response;
    if (success) {
      dispatch({ type: FETCH_MATCHES, payload});
    } else {
     dispatch({ type: FETCH_MATCHES_FAILED}); /* or show notification */ . 
    }
  );
};
```

Let me know if this works out.